# Read parcelable not working while writing does

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I am
send data from one service to other service using parecable, when I write data contains proper value but when read data from parcelable it return null values.

can any one tell me what is the problem with this code?

Parcelable class

```
package com.airwatch.agent.finddevice;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;


/**
 * Represents the configuration supplied from device services 
 * regarding the  find device command.
 */
public class FindDeviceConfig implements Parcelable{
    public FindDeviceConfig() {
    }

    /**
     * number of loops to play ring-tone.
     */
    private String numberoftime;

    /**
     * Delay between loops - in seconds.
     */
    private String interval;

    public FindDeviceConfig(String numberoftime, String interval) {
        this.numberoftime = numberoftime;
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public String getNumberoftime() {
        return numberoftime;
    }

    public void setNumberoftime(String numberoftime) {
        this.numberoftime = numberoftime;
    }

    public String getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(String interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        //dest.writeInt(Integer.parseInt(numberoftime));

        //dest.writeInt(Integer.parseInt(interval));
        dest.writeString(this.interval);
        dest.writeString(this.numberoftime);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<FindDeviceConfig> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<FindDeviceConfig>() {
        public FindDeviceConfig createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new FindDeviceConfig(in);
        }

        public FindDeviceConfig[] newArray(int size) {
            return new FindDeviceConfig[size];
        }
    };

    public FindDeviceConfig(Parcel parcel)
    {
        parcel.setDataPosition(0);

        interval=parcel.readString();
        numberoftime=parcel.readString();

    }
}
```

Putting the parcelable object.

```
FindDeviceConfig config=new FindDeviceConfig("3","2");
intent.putExtra("finddevice_config", config);
```

Reading the parcelable object.

```
FindDeviceConfig config = intent.getParcelableExtra("finddevice_config");
```

Anyone faced this problem?

Comment: have u tried with removing `parcel.setDataPosition(0);`

Comment: `parcel.setDataPosition(0);` yes exactly this may be the problem.

Comment: thanks but i have tried its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following constructor:

```
public FindDeviceConfig(Parcel data) {
    this.numberoftime  = data.readString();
    this.interval = data.readString();
 }
```

Comment: i already added this constructor in my code just see in the bottom of code

Comment: try the following
bundle b = new bundle();
b.putParcelable("finddevice_config", config);
intent.putExtras(b);

Read the parcelable object 

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
FindDeviceConfig config  = bundle.getParcelable(""finddevice_config"");

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but a different solution, so posting here for future reference.

The most important thing to keep in mind while using `Parcelable` is that the order in which you write your variables to the Parcel should also be the order in which you read it.

For example,

```
//wirting to Parcel
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {       
    dest.writeString(this.interval); //interval first
    dest.writeString(this.numberoftime); //numberoftime second
} 

//reading from Parcel 
public FindDeviceConfig(Parcel parcel)
{  
    Wrong order -- this will not work or give unwanted result

    numberoftime=parcel.readString(); 
    interval=parcel.readString();
} 

//Correct Order
public FindDeviceConfig(Parcel parcel)
{           
    interval=parcel.readString(); //interval first
    numberoftime=parcel.readString(); //numberoftime second
}
```

Happy coding :)